# operate with loop in unmanaged c++ dll from c#(callbacks)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, callback

I have written an unmanaged c++ dll that works good (IPinvoke))) There is one resource-consuming function in it - there is a loop with complex time consuming logic. What is the best way to calculate percentage of this loop progress and sending break to this loop - using callbacks or may be passing parameters? 
 If callbacks is the most good variant - could anyone provide sample?

in dll:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) uint8* resourceConsumingFunction(uint8* dataBufer)
{
  //there is a loop with many math here
  return dataBuffer;
}
```

in c#

```
[DllImport("MyLib.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern byte* resourceConsumingFunction(byte* dataBuf);
//.....
byte* bufbuf = resourceConsumingFunction(data);//there I need to break this function and to get //percentage
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to provide help about a dll you said nothing about. Where's the code ?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/win32_to_net.aspx

Comment: Calculate it by hand?  Just post the code your asking about.

Comment: Is there a chance that `resourceConsumingFunction()` will run more than once at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a callback can work.  You'll need a function pointer in the C++ code, something like this:

```
typedef void (__stdcall * pfnCallback)(int progress, int* cancel);

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) 
uint8* resourceConsumingFunction(uint8* dataBuffer, pfnCallback callback)
{
    for (int progress = 0;;) {
        int cancel = 0;
        callback(progress, &cancel);
        if (cancel) return null;
        // More code
        //...
    }
    return dataBuffer;
}
```

And the equivalent C# code would be:

```
private void delegate pfnCallback(int progress, out bool cancel);

private void makeCall() {
    var callback = new pfnCallback(showProgress);
    var bufptr = resourceConsumingFunction(somebuf, callback);
    GC.KeepAlive(callback);
    // etc...
}

private void showProgress(int progress, out bool cancel) {
   // etc...
}
```

Using __stdcall for the callback helps keep the delegate declaration simple.  The GC.KeepAlive() call is necessary to stop the garbage collector from collecting the delegate object too soon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is very helpfull for me/ the last questino is about callback(progress, &cancel);  function in c++ - it must somehow calculate progress - but why it is void? May be it is noob question but I don't understand this function syntax. May be something like(in c++): int callback(int progr, bool cancel){ /*progr = (val*100)/total (- something logic)*/ return progr;} ?

Comment: Sorry Hans! I have not understand your post at first. Read it more and more cafully + coding helped me. The only question I have is - where to count percentage? I think it mus be count in dll couse the loop it there ?  So the syntax of callback (see previouse my comment) must by defined in c++ dll as i have wrote?

Comment: I beg your pardon once more, Hans. I have understand your code completely - this is very good example ) and you is a real guru)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the info you provided, I think you'll have to rewrite your dll from scratch.

I'd make it a BackgroundWorker, like this (pseudocode, look it up on MSDN):

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

worker.DoWork += (s,e) => 
{
    loop(loopcondition)
    {
        ... math magic, in which you also calculate percentage ...
        worker.ReportProgress(percentage); // fire 'ProgressChanged' event handled below
    }
};

worker.ProgressChanged += (s,e) => { /*e.ProgressPercentage is the value you passed, here you handle it*/ };

//WARNING: i don't remember the exact event name right now, look it up!
worker.WorkerCompleted += (s,e) => { /*when job is done, you can do something here*/ };
```

you can interact with UI in the `ProgressChanged` and `WorkerCompleted` events, not in `DoWork` (it's being run in a separate thread).

Comment: So, you're suggesting to rewrite the DLL into C#?